# Install Radeon X1650 driver on Debian Wheezy

Tags: amd-radeon, debian-wheezy, display-driver

I'm trying to setup my ATI graphics card (X1650) on Debian Wheezy.

None of the instructions I came across worked.

I always get this:

```
sudo aticonfig --lsa
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of sudo lspci -vnn |grep -A 12 VGA

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't yet, I suggest you to read [this](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo#Installing_proprietary_firmware) official documentation. Running:

```
aptitude install firmware-linux-nonfree
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Still getting this after reboot when I type `aticonfig`
`aticonfig: No supported adapters detected`

Comment: Very strange. Run a "lspci -v | grep VGA" without the quotes.

Comment: `VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV535 [Radeon X1650 Series] (rev 9e) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`